# Fatal Error on admin page After upgrading from magento connect

Tags: magento-1.7, localhost

after upgrading extensions and some modules from magento connect and trying to reconnect to admin panel i got this message below:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method `Zend_Date::toString_shamsi()` in `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Data.php` on line 184

i try to fix it with replacing zend folder in `app/code/core` but it doesnt work,please show me the way!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As @Barbanet mention.

> The message is telling you that there are some class calling a method
>   called toString_shamsi() on Zend_Date and that method doesn't exists.

But to my knowledge/google `toString_shamsi()` doesn't exist period.

If you take a look at app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Data.php from a fresh version of magento 1.7

```
public function formatDate($date = null, $format = Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT, $showTime = false)
{
    if (!in_array($format, $this->_allowedFormats, true)) {
        return $date;
    }
    if (!($date instanceof Zend_Date) && $date && !strtotime($date)) {
        return '';
    }
    if (is_null($date)) {
        $date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtTimestamp(), null, null);
    } else if (!$date instanceof Zend_Date) {
        $date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(strtotime($date), null, null);
    }

    if ($showTime) {
        $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat($format);
    } else {
        $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat($format);
    }

    return $date->toString($format);  <- Line 184
}
```

See https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php#L184

So I would strongly recommend doing a diff on your code base with a fresh copy of magento of the same version (also remember to apply all the patches that are currently installed on your store)

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you that there are some class calling a method called toString_shamsi() on Zend_Date and that method doesn't exists.

What's happens if you search for "toString_shamsi" into your project?

You'll need to find who's calling that method.